# Broadcom STA driver module options

Tags: wifi

I am using Broadcom BCM43142BGN wireless chip and living connectivity issues.
i think i need to configure wl module options. Here is the output of `modinfo wl` command:

```
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string
```

What all those options mean ? Which options should i configure ?

Answer (score 0):

If you experience connectivity issues with BCM43142, the problem can be likely resolved by improving wifi signal strength by changing channel to another one. Also, increasing number of beacons will help.

I have the same chipset and it was breaking the connection every 30 min. After changing channel it improved to breaking once a day. After increasing beacons it resolved completely. I checked the logs and there was no disconnect in 2 weeks time.

I have another BCM4313 and this one didn't disconnect even once in months time even the strength is weak. I think it's limited just to some chipset class and not whole `wl` driver.